# Twilio Conversation LastReadMessageIndex Always null when you get connect with client first time

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

I am using twilio conversation api for chat application. I have enabled read horizon from settings. I am marking message read index and also getting unread count. But when I refresh the page lastMessageRead index is always null. I have added screenshot for update and null. I don't is it a bug in SDK of what. I am adding screenshot of service setting as well. Need help what I am doing wrong.

[image: Service Settings]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you loading those conversations onto the page to get that attribute.

Comment: Using join event

Comment: Can you share the code you’re using?

Comment: const Conversations = require('@twilio/conversations');
// getting token from server
 const client = await Conversations.Client.create(res.token);
 client.on('conversationJoined', throttle((conversation) => {}));

Comment: every time I reconnect the client one of the participant has updated read index but conversation overall is null, but when I update it , it becomes available.

Comment: Sorry for the delay here, the team was checking in on this. We think this is a bug and are raising a ticket internally to work out what is going on.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of twilio-conversations you are using?

Comment: its 1.1.0 version

Comment: I have raised this as an issue internally, but just to make sure, can you update the SDK to the latest [version 1.2.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio/conversations/v/1.2.3) and let me know if it is still happening?

Comment: Ok, for a workaround we moved to setAllMessageRead() function instead of index based marking.

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan did it fix the index becoming null after you restart client? The two seem to be unrelated.

Comment: Yes seems like its fixed I have index when I restart client.

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan This is very suspicious, I don't see how setting the index differently could've affected the property on the other side. Could you share your (relevant) code somewhere?

Comment: I updated the library as you told then that fixed the issue.

Comment: Okay then, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a conversationJoined event, this means you have left it before?

If you leave the conversation at some point, the read horizon will be cleared.

Comment: No I'm not leaving it, I am just setting up client again.